# Why is $\left(\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac{\left(-x^{4}\right)^{n}}{n !}\right) 2 x=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}(-1)^{n} \frac{2 \cdot x^{4 n+1}}{n !}$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

How do we integrate $2x$ on the left into the sum such that $\left(\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac{\left(-x^{4}\right)^{n}}{n !}\right) 2 x=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}(-1)^{n} \frac{2 \cdot x^{4 n+1}}{n !}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every $N\in\mathbb{N}$ You have by the distributive law:
$$\left(\sum_{n=0}^{N}\frac{(-x^4)^n}{n!}\right)2x=\sum_{n=0}^{N}\frac{(-x^4)^n2x}{n!}=\sum_{n=0}^{N}(-1)^n\frac{2x^{4n+1}}{n!}.$$

Comment: thanks, what did you do in the last step?

Comment: Just a  basic computation $(-x^4)^n2x=((-1)x^4)^n2x=(-1)^n(x^4)^n2x=(-1)^n2x^{4n}x=(-1)^n2x^{4n+1}$